# CLass ''Form' Not Found

Tags: php, laravel

Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found laravel 5.0

Comment: If you haven't done so you need to install Illuminate/Html package by adding to your composer.json and doing composer update. Its is no longer available by default in laravel 5

Answer (score 0):

**Simply follow 4 step**
 
**1) Go root directory find and edit composer.json - In that file write "illuminate/html": "^5.0" in require array.**

**2) Goto cmd and goto your folder directory and ** composer update **run this command**

**3) Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:**

'providers' => [
           'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
  ],

**4) Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:**

'aliases' => [

```
  'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
  'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

],
After all this finished 
**Restart your laravel server** :-- php artisan serve --port=8880
Now you can use Any Html tag in your view blade

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a much stupider mistake that I was making (although the provided answer works perfectly for the real issue).

What I was doing was continually editing the wrong `composer` file. I had one composer file outside of my `laravel` directory that was obviously not going to make any difference in my application.

When I did all of the recommended updated to the **real** composer file, everything worked fine.